# maven and lift using scala 2.8 : lift-mapper missing?

Tags: maven-2, scala, jetty, scala-2.8, lift

Newbie question since I'm not up to speed using 
maven at all.

I'm trying to use scala + lift using scala 2.8, environment
is a win7 box if that matters.

I create a basic project using:

```
mvn archetype:generate -U   -DarchetypeGroupId=net.liftweb -DarchetypeArtifactId=lift-archetype-basic   -DarchetypeVersion=2.0-scala280-SNAPSHOT   -DarchetypeRepository=http://scala-tools.org/repo-snapshots  -DremoteRepositories=http://scala-tools.org/repo-snapshots   -DgroupId=com.liftworkshop
  -DartifactId=todo  -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

So far so good, but then, I try to cd into my new project
and do:

```
mvn jetty:run
```

I after quite a few downloads end up with a error like below:

```
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.

Missing:
----------
1) net.liftweb:lift-mapper:jar:2.0-scala280-SNAPSHOT

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command:
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=net.liftweb -DartifactId=lift-mapper -D
version=2.0-scala280-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:

      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=net.liftweb -DartifactId=lift-mapper -Dve
rsion=2.0-scala280-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -Dr
epositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency:
        1) com.liftworkshop:todo:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) net.liftweb:lift-mapper:jar:2.0-scala280-SNAPSHOT

----------
1 required artifact is missing.

for artifact:
  com.liftworkshop:todo:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT

from the specified remote repositories:
  scala-tools.snapshots (http://scala-tools.org/repo-snapshots),
  scala-tools.releases (http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases),
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created the same project using the `mvn archetype:generate` command you provided but I couldn't reproduce your problem. The [`lift-mapper-2.0-scala280-SNAPSHOT.jar`](http://scala-tools.org/repo-snapshots/net/liftweb/lift-mapper/2.0-scala280-SNAPSHOT/lift-mapper-2.0-scala280-SNAPSHOT.jar) artifact is definitely in the scala [snapshots repository](http://scala-tools.org/repo-snapshots/) and Maven downloaded it:

```
...
1619K downloaded  (lift-mapper-2.0-scala280-SNAPSHOT.jar)
[WARNING] *** CHECKSUM FAILED - Checksum failed on download: local = '0c857e2c5de9d5cabb7c972e519528606f19697b'; remote = 'a258cf7d7a49a8d7163d499da06a4d1e231a78e0' - RETRYING
Downloading: http://scala-tools.org/repo-snapshots/net/liftweb/lift-mapper/2.0-scala280-SNAPSHOT/lift-mapper-2.0-scala280-SNAPSHOT.jar
1619K downloaded  (lift-mapper-2.0-scala280-SNAPSHOT.jar)
```

As you can see, Maven had to retry the download because of a failed CHECKSUM check but it worked.

Just try again.

Comment: Thanks alot. It must have been a temporary thing, because when I tried 1h later with exactkly the same setup, it worked.